# Half character? - Accents encoding issue

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I'm currently facing a very strange encoding issue when dealing with an html source code.
I got the following line:

> "requête présentée par..."

When an extern library does an utf8_decode I got:

> "reque^te présente´e par..."

So accents are placed right to the accented characters. If I do an utf8_encode from that result, I don't get the original "requête présentée par..." but I keep having "reque^te présente´e par..."

Even stranger: If I open the original html in Notepad++, encoding is utf8 without BOM (so far, so good) but I can actually select half of the character with the text selection (keyboard or mouse). Yes, half of it. As if the real code was "e^" but it was displayed as "ê". When I try to copy it to my IDE it copies "ê" but pastes "e^".

I have come up with a basic replacement function:

"e^"  => "ê",
"e´"  => "é",
...

and some other french cases, and it's working properly for now.
But as the HTML comes in differents languages, I'm pretty sure I won't be able to successfully replace every character under this encoding issue.

Has anybody face this issue before and (hopefully) has a more general solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your content-type utf-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your HTML source is using [Combining characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Combining_characters).  That is, instead of using a single unicode character to represent the ê, it's using first a regular `e` and then a combining character to add the diacritic `^`.  You can verify this with a hex editor to see the character codes, in this case the combining circumflex is hex code 0302.

See also [Unicode equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence).

Comment: You might be right. "ê" hex codes are:
"\x65\xcc\x82"

Comment: Ah ok, so 0xCC 0x82 is the UTF-8 representation of 0302.  As if it wasn't weird enough! So you need to "normalize" this before you pass it on to your external decoding library, and convert it to a single 00EA (in UTF-8 0xC3 0xAA)

Comment: Thanks. Still haven't got this solved but I will give a try to http://www.php.net/manual/fr/normalizer.normalize.php class, which seems to convert NFD to NFC code point.

Comment: Even if it didn't solve my problem it gave me a very important hint, so I think this deserves to be marked as answered :)